# Adding a fragment causes crash

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm stuck with a fragment-related problem.  I have a splash screen that will "load" for 3 secs and then will create a new `Intent` and start the `MainActivity`.

The main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.MainActivity">


    <fragment
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:name="com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.NewsFragment"
       ></fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the xml for the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.NewsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and here's the error I'm getting (full trace [here](http://pastebin.com/b2VRU4JJ)):

```
10-26 12:05:05.153 2855-2855/com.example.paolo.ebolatrack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 12:05:05.153 2855-2855/com.example.paolo.ebolatrack E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.paolo.ebolatrack, PID: 2855
10-26 12:05:05.153 2855-2855/com.example.paolo.ebolatrack E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.paolo.ebolatrack/com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
...
```

Adding the fragment seems to crash the app.  I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: You should post the relevant code here

Comment: where is your fragment class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have answer :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.NewsFragment
```

Add id for your fragment in layout xml:

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/some_frag"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:name="com.example.paolo.ebolatrack.NewsFragment"
   ></fragment>
```

this is missing line :

```
 android:id="@+id/some_frag"
```

Comment: tryed and working ! thank u man..i dunno why but i complete missed that line in my mind

Comment: i have one more question: what does mean? A <fragment> tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
i 've just added the id

Comment: i've fixed adding:         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news"></fragment>

but what that do ?

Comment: I don't know you can check in documentation

Comment: Why are you making edits to questions with only minor formatting changes?